# Ul not disappearing please advice

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I am trying to practice a drop down menu.I want the "Third" to appear below the "Second" whenever I hover on the "Second". For that, I have used the famous technique of `ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}` but it does not seems to be working. The "Third" is permanently hidden and does not pops up on hovering. Could someone please advice as to where I am wrong?

code:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  /* [disabled]display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: A `ul` is not a valid child of a `ul`

Comment: Consider making a codepen : http://codepen.io/LittleNooby/pen/YWPrMP

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid HTML because `ul > ul` is not valid. Move you inner `ul` to `li` of `Second`:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  /* [disabled]display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second

    <ul>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `drop down` menu should be `child` of `li` so your html must be like this

```css
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
}

ul {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
/* [disabled]display: inline-block; */
text-align: center;
height: auto;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

ul li {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

ul ul {
display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> First </li>
  <li> 
    Second
    <ul>
      <li> Third </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You 2nd `ul` should be inside `li` to make it work.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;    
}

ul {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  list-style: none;
  /* [disabled]display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li> First </li>
  <li> Second
    <ul>
      <li> Third </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But now the problem is that when the "Third" appears, the position of the "First" moves. The "First" also moves down on hovering.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
width:294px;
height:50px;
padding-left:0;
margin:0;
background:#CCCCCC;
}
ul > li{
list-style:none;
display:inline;
padding:13px 19px;
font-size:24px;
float:left;
}
ul > li > ul{
margin:10px -10px;
padding-left:0;
width:auto;
height:55px;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul > li > ul > li{
display:block;
list-style-type:none;
}
ul > li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>
Second
<ul>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This code looks great. And works fine. But could you please tell how to CENTER the text "THIRD" in the drop down menu?  I tried giving `margin:auto , auto` in the `ul > li > ul > li { }` But the text alignment tends to be on the right.I understand that in the above code you have given `padding-left:10px;` for `ul > li > ul > li { }` But it is like a manual instruction. Hence, depending on the length and font size of the text one has to calculate the padding value. However,I am looking for something that can automatically center the text Irrespective of the length and font size. Like text align

Comment: Check above updated code that work fine. Just remove padding-left:10px; from ul > li > ul > li and set width auto of ul > li > ul. Thus this aligns your text automatically in center.

Comment: Yes, the THIRD looks almost in the center now. But why is there extra space on the right of FOURTH? How do I alogn FIRST SECOND FOURTH exactly in the middle?

Comment: Check updated code above. You can adjust that using padding and width.